# How to describe a `multipart/form-data` request in blueprint documentation standard?

Tags: api, documentation, apiblueprint

i'm trying to document an API and one of these endpoints works as `multipart/form-data` content-type recipient to catch user uploads, and the whole other endpoints works as `application/json` content-type recipients.

In my documentation i have documented all `json` requests as properly `json` objects, but in the `multipart/form-data` idk how to describe it.

EX 1 - JSON Endpoint:

```
{
   "data": {
         "name": "username",
         "email": "email@example.com"
   }
}
```

Now i dont know how to describe this object as `multipart/form-data` object, using de Blueprint API Docs standard.

Can someone help me?